# D-Link DIR 615 suddenly stopped working. it is happening everyday

Tags: router

My Dlink DIR 615, is working good but once a day it is stop working and I have to do soft reset or hard reset to get it up running again.
I have done the factory setting and Crash reset and still I have a same problem. everyday I have to do the same.
Can any one help me?
Thanks

Comment: That's not a very detailed problem description. When it has stopped working, can you reach its administrative web page? Can you ping it? What exactly are the symptoms?

Comment: yes, I can reach administrative web page, can ping it and just i have to reboot it to get it up running...

Comment: It could be dns problem too if router works as dns relay. You can try to use some website by ip address or override dns settings. google dns service is 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 1):

First check if there is any firmware updates, check out d-link ftp directory for these.

Take some notes about usage, how many users when lockup occur. Does problem occur only under heavy load (lot of connections, lot of half open conn, specific protocols, how many arp users, dhcpd problems are also common). Check if there anyting found from device logs.

Try to use minimal features if possible: static ip's, no routing other than default, simple firewall with drop (do not send error responses), wlan disabled, access control disabled, ... disabled. If it works try to enable needed services one at time and see if it crashes to find problematic settings/services.

To name few other possible causes it can also be bad powersupply, dust, temperature, broken capasitor(s) ...

Comment: It could also just be old.